# python json match multiple and replace

Tags: python, json

Need your help in finding a solution . I have the following json

[{"source":"AA","target":"BB","metric":"10","local_interface":"100","remote_interface":"200"},
{"source":"AA","target":"BB","metric":"10","local_interface":"111","remote_interface":"222"},
{"source":"BB","target":"AA","metric":"10","local_interface":"200","remote_interface":"100"}]

the goal is to :

- get first element (ie: pattern ) as source/target/local_interface
- search remaining elements for something matching source=pattern.target , target=pattern.source , remote_interface=pattern.local_interface
- remove the element from json.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: So where's your code, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you after something as simple as this?

```
j = [{"source":"AA","target":"BB","metric":"10",
 "local_interface":"100","remote_interface":"200"},
 {"source":"AA","target":"BB","metric":"10",
 "local_interface":"111","remote_interface":"222"},
 {"source":"BB","target":"AA","metric":"10",
 "local_interface":"200","remote_interface":"100"}]

s = j[0]["source"]
print(s)
t = j[0]["target"]
print(t)
li = j[0]["local_interface"]
print(li)

print('Find source ==', t)
for i in range(1,3):
  if j[i]['source'] == t:
    print("Is match:", j[i])

print()

del(j[1])
print("after deletion:", j)
```

Comment: thx Jorgen. I need to check against all three values. I guess if j[i]['source'] == t and j[i]['target'] == s and j[i]['remote_interface'] == li: will work

Comment: Certainly. And the array element to delete is the index in i